# python: Using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

I was recently asked to print a nested tuple using recursion logic. I'm not sure about recursion. 
I just learning python and very new to this topic please explain.

Here is question given to me.

Print a nested tuple in a separate line using recursion:

```
Print (1,2,('a', 'b', (6,9,7)), 6,('$','@'))
```

Each item should print in the line

[image]

Comment: Please post your code attempt.

Comment: x = (1,2,('a', 'b', (6,9,7)), 6,('$','@'))
for y in x:
 print y

Comment: If you want recursion you'll need a function. Start with writing a function that accepts a `tuple` as a parameter and then prints each tuple entry.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use recursion, you could use something like this:

```
def print_recursive(base_element):                                
     if hasattr(base_element, '__iter__'):
         for element in base_element:
             print_recursive(element)
     else:
         print(base_element)
print_recursive((1,2,('a', 'b', (6,9,7)), 6,('$','@')))
```

Comment: Can you please explain this line what that is doing? if hasattr(base_element, '__iter__'):

Comment: @dino110 : I suppose you refer to the second line. It basically checks if `base_element` is iterable (list, tuple, dict, ...)

Comment: Ok I just  tried it it goes in infinite loop cursion.............recursionExample.py", line 4, in print_recursive
    print_recursive(element)

Comment: If I don't use recursion what is a diff method of doing this I hav not used the function hasattr

Comment: @dino110 it means that you have an error in your file. When I ran this exemple it works.

Comment: @dino110 without recursion you should use loop for every nested level. If you don't want to use hasattr(base_element, '__iter__') you can check by type (e.g. tuple and list) or collections.Iterable

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov yup worked in other editor. Question what __iter__ doing?

Comment: @dino110 Eric already answered you, but I can repeat. It's a method of object which return an iterator. You could read more https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov Thanks for providing the guidance I'm new and learning basic of python. Really appreciate your help.